# Android studio /git after merge i got this response

Tags: android

[image: After merge i got this response]
 ===>git push has failed 
for i done below step
1.vcs - commit==> it was commit in local 
2.vcs- update project=>select option=>branch,stash
after that i got the response that was screen shot (which was show in below picture)
1.vcs - commit==> it was commit in local 
2.vcs- update project=>select option=>branch,stash
after that i got the response that was screen shot (which was show in below picture)

Answer (score 0):

**Why cause this :**

It seems that your local commit has some conflict with origin/master.
For example, your teammate add the code

```
special_equipment_usedschedule...
```

And you add the code

```
decline_order...
special_equipment_usedschedule...
```

Then there will happen a conflict.

**How can I do :**
You can solve the conflict.
For example, choose your code (between <<<<

I am sorry that I can not say more clearlly.

But you can reference this link :
https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/

Thanks.